# Replace Complete String - Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: string, kettle, regexp-replace, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I would like to replace the whole phrase in a field. I am working in pentaho. Is there a way to do that? first i do a look up of key words and then replace the whole string with a new one.
[image]

And want to replace all the field with the "Replace with" only. In this case it must say DVR only.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with like this:

- use RegEx: Y;
- Search: `.*(DVR).*`
- Replace with: `$1`